# Export to excel is empty for user grid with custom UniGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, content-management-system, kentico

I have implemented custom user grid in cmsdesk adminstration section.
I have added custom page as Unigrid.ascx for binding dataset.

A have added Query in User_List.aspx page as

```
<cms:UniGrid ID="gridElem" Query="cms.user.SelectCustomUserSearch" runat="server" GridName="User_List.xml" OrderBy="UserName"
                IsLiveSite="false" />
```

on custom UniGrid.ascx.cs page bind dataset in `RetrieveData()` method as

```
ds = ConnectionHelper.ExecuteQuery(Query, parameters);
```

searching, paging , sorting is working fine. but when I export to excel it is get empty excel sheet.

how can I write excel with custom UniGrid.ascx control.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here are the options you have:

1. Debug AdvancedExport.ascx.cs which ensures the export functionality. It also contains UniGridExportHelper - check its public property DataSource. If it's null the problem will be in retrieving data (where condition / top n etc.), if it won't the data might be corrupted (stripped of html etc.)
2. Download [Open XML SDK Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425) and check whether the excel is really empty. (Check shared string table etc.)
3. If you have source code you can debug directly the UniGridExportHelper.
4. Check other formats - CSV / XML - are they also empty?